# I cant find any documentation for g_io_channel_win32_make_pollfd

Tags: c++, c, gtk, glib

Is there a documentation available for `g_io_channel_win32_make_pollfd`?

I want to use this function to create FDs on Windows for IPC between the main thread and a separate thread.

It is only briefly mentioned [here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-poll) and doesn't really explain how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's the source code](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc#amB2gY01WFw/glib-2.9.2/glib/giowin32.c&q=g_io_channel_win32_make_pollfd), and there's also a [testcase](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=4&ct=rc#G7odZkRgJ_g/glib-2.2.3/tests/gio-test.c&q=g_io_channel_win32_make_pollfd) that uses it. Documentation is available in the [header it's declared in](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc#G7odZkRgJ_g/glib-2.2.3/glib/giochannel.h&q=g_io_channel_win32_make_pollfd%20lang:c). If that documentation doesn't appear in the manual, you might want to file a bug with the glib people - it's probably being excluded from the documentation generator due to a bug of some sort.

Comment: Still not documented. Current link to the source is https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/master/glib/giochannel.h .